# Accessible proofs of contemporary results in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

Are there strong results in contemporary mathematical research (last 20 years) which have a proof which every mathematician (holding a PhD) can completely understand within a few days? -- If yes, please give examples. If not, please explain the phenomenon.

Comment: There are some pretty weak PhDs out there, so on those grounds the answer is "no". But if you mean "a good mathematician who is not an expert", then I would say "yes".

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/129759/modern-mathematical-achievements-accessible-to-undergraduates

Comment: Already 3 votes to close ? I think this is an interesting soft question, and *not* an exact duplicate of the question 129759 : there is a difference between a proof understandable by an undergraduate, and a proof understandable by most active mathematicians. The former supposes a low-level proof (in the sense of not using any sophisticated notion: no manifolds, no Lie Groups, no representations, no complex analysis, etc.) which will be in general, as a matter of compensation, quite technical. Here the OP is asking for nice theorems outside of my field that I could understand quickly...

Comment: Another problem is that it is not clear to me what a "strong result" is.

Comment: Igor, I'm curious about what results you have in mind.

Comment: Dear Deane Yang, I would say a result is strong if it is published in an A journal, cited and some experts in the field would consider the result as strong

Comment: Dear Joel, this is exactly the way I would like the question to be understood.

Comment: Dear Igor, I mean a reasonable mathematician holding a PhD which is not an expert in field. What results do you think about?

Answer (score 13):

I think "Primes is in P" is accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of such results in combinatorics. The [Wilf–Zeilberger method](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) is perhaps the "strongest" one that I can think of off the top of my head. It is strong by any reasonable definition of the word. With a more precise definition of "strong" I could probably come up with others.

Comment: Dear Timothy Chow ,I would say a result is strong if it is published in an A journal, cited and some experts in the field would consider the result as strong. Very Best.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite from the last few years is the proof by Hugo Duminil-Copin and Stanislav Smirnov that the connective constant of the honeycomb lattice is $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$: http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0575

Answer (score 5):

Manjul Bhargava's proof of the [15 theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems) (in *Quadratic Forms and Their Applications*, Contemp. Math. **272**, 1999) is strikingly simple, especially when contrasted with Conway and Schneeberger's original, intricate proof.

Answer (score 3):

How about the saturation conjecture? It is a quite strong result, and I believe the proof should be accessible within that time, see
[www.math.rutgers.edu/~asbuch/papers/sat.ps](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~asbuch/papers/sat.ps)